# Call ViewBag, ViewData, TempData in external js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In MVC Application, I want to get ViewBag, ViewData, TempData values in external .js file.
I dont want to write scripting in view.cshtml, so I added external js file to it. But I am unable to call this ViewBag, ViewData, TempData values in that js file.

Can anyone tell me how to call these values without writing any js code in view.cshtml

Comment: You have to write atleast one line of js code to read the value and assign it to a js variable which your external js can use

Answer (score 3):

if you want to avoid any scripting in the cshtml then just set a hidden field to the value you want to pass the alert.
Controller:

```
TempData["Message"] = "My message text";
```

View:

```
@if(TempData["Message"]) {
  <input type="text" id="tempdata" class="hidden" 
    value="@TempData["Message"]"/>
}
```

JS:

```
var tempMessage = document.getElementById('tempdata') ? 
         document.getElementById('tempdata').value : null;
if(tempMessage) { alert(tempMessage); };
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the Razor code runs on the server side, those values aren't available to Javascript which runs on the client side.  The only way I know of getting around this is to declare some variables that in your `.js` file and initialize them in your `.cshtml` file.  Perhaps not ideal for you, but I hope it helps.

my.cshtml:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
   myVar = @(ViewBag.myVar);  // etc.
</script>
...
```

my.js

```
var myVar = null;

function myFunc() {
   // Check for initialization
   if (myVar == null)
      alert("myVar not initialized!");
   ...
   // use myVar
   ...
}
```

Comment: Just want to point out that you should *always* namespace your JavaScript variables, especially when declaring in the global scope like this.